# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: brave/internal/HexCodec after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.3.8.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to upgrade my SpringBoot version from 2.0.x to 2.3.8.RELEASE. After the update, on refreshing the Spring Config Server, I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: brave/internal/HexCodec in my application logs. My app is deployed over PCF and uses below dependencies in addition to company's internal dependency.

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <spring.cloud.vault.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.cloud.vault.version>
        <spring-cloud-config-client>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-config-client>
        <spring.cloud.services.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.cloud.services.version>
        <spring.cloud.dependencies.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring.cloud.dependencies.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.services.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.vault.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.savoirtech.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-json-logger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-config-client}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I assume I am getting this issue because of Zipkins being used in Spring Sleuth(We have this in our company's internal dependency). I tried setting spring.zepkin.enabled=false and I also tried to create the below bean with org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.2.8.RELEASE but still I got the same error.

```
@Bean
Reporter<Span> reporter() {
    return Reporter.NOOP;
}
```

Application console error message: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: brave/internal/HexCodec

At this point, I am not even sure if I am on right track or not. Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use the latest of that release train: [`Hoxton.SR11`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Hoxton-Release-Notes) and the latest Spring Boot [`2.3.x`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.3.12.RELEASE/jar)?

With these you should see `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:2.2.8.RELEASE` with the matching Sleuth dependencies. This should ensure that you are using the right version of Brave.

If this does not work, please check your dependency tree and the Spring Cloud BOM and ensure you are using the right versions.